# Issue with datetime field when adding more than one InfoPath form web part on the same SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, infopath, infopath2010

I created two lists in a SharePoint site: tbdl1 and tbdl2.
tbdl1 contains two datetime fields. One of these fields has default value set to now().
tbdl2 contains no additional fields other than title.

From list settings for each list, I customise and publish their InfoPath form (edit) to SharePoint.

Next, I add an InfoPath form web part to a SharePoint site and configure it to display tbdl1.
Until now, I can change the date time field fine.

**The problem:**
I add another InfoPath form web part to the same page and configure it to display tbdl2.
I try to change the date time field in tbdl1. The date field always resets to today's date. See illustration below.

[image]

Is this a SharePoint 2010 issue, InfoPath issue, or am I doning something wrong? You help is much appreciated.

Comment: it seems like if you put more one infopath web parts in the same web part zone, the one with the date time field needs to be at the very bottom of the zone for it to function properly. if there is any additional (infopath) web part below the one containing date time field, the issue comes back up. 

since this is not a solution and just a temporary work around, i am not adding this comment as a solution. if anyone can explain why this is happening, it would be great help. i will be looking into this myself. thank you.